# Вернуть Int ищу не Brute Force алгоритм

Tags: java, алгоритм, kotlin

Задача простая, вернуть Int, на вход получаем String (нескольких типов). Нужно вернуть Int максимально приблеженный.

```
//12M -> 12000000
//26.8M -> 26800000
//47K  -> 47000
//27.8K -> 27800
//1,171 -> 1171
//232 -> 232
```

Интересует не столько готовый код, сколько обсудить наиболее лаконичную и эффективную идею.
Я вижу так:

1. Прверяем строку на содержание букв "K", "M", ","
2. Проверяем есть ли "." Если нет, берем все что до позиции К или М каким нибудь substring() Умножаем на 1_000 или на 1_000_000 в зависимости от ветки выполнения.
3. Если есть . то считаем положение точки ... Сабстринг .... В общем у меня строк на 40 решение выйдет. Чуть позже добавлю его.

Может есть у кого-то не брут форс методы, а то алгоритмы не моя сильная сторона.

П.С. Задача не с Codewars/LeetCode а с реального проекта

Comment: Нужно описать условие задачи

Comment: Не совсем ясно, что вы имеете ввиду, когда говорите про [брут форс](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Полный_перебор) методы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[tio.run](https://tio.run/##ZZDBa4MwGMXv@SsegYKCC2hHLSvbabcxGPS47ZBpFFuNksTOUfzbXfxat8EOIV9eXt77kYM8yZtDfpymrJbW4sW0pZENzgzo@o@6ymCddH7LW39U6KSxKtg7U@nSX5mQrIBRrjcaj@QS5LrMgTcJo7paZirgEY/AefgrPM2CWv@Vnkna8DDc@eiR/UM5tVWORlb6yvH6DmlKu6AUrcFCOOAOWn3ix3gGjxNqSDZiS8NtShBJKrY0xFGcxqSsE45xiQX2X9apRrS9E52Pc0XAVxb3D1gVb9o/GKLr9wwX9Bl@XuM0@U5Ghcy3Mapi1MN8yTc)

```
class Program {
  public static double parse(String str) {
    return Double.parseDouble(str.replace(",", "").replace("K", "e3").replace("M", "e6"));
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (String x : new String[] { "12M", "26.8M", "47K", "27.8K", "1,171", "232" }) {
      System.out.printf("%s => %f\n", x, parse(x));
    }
  }
}
```

```
12M => 12000000.000000
26.8M => 26800000.000000
47K => 47000.000000
27.8K => 27800.000000
1,171 => 1171.000000
232 => 232.000000
```

Если нужно целое, то можно после `Double.parseDouble` привести к `int` или `long` (впрочем, вместо 63 точных битов можно рассчитывать только на 53).

Comment: Просто и понятно, без регулярок )

Comment: @Kromster, насколько я помню, в джаве replace первым параметром принимает как раз регулярку? xD

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю такую реализацию. Создаем `enum` со всеми префиксами и их значениями:

```kotlin
enum class Metric(val prefix: String, val multiplier: Int) {
    MEGA("M", 1_000_000),
    KILO("K", 1_000),
    NONE("", 1),
}
```

Далее, пишем такую вспомогательную функцию по парсингу строки в число:

```kotlin
fun parse(string: String): Long {
    for (metric in Metric.values()) {
        if (string.endsWith(metric.prefix)) {
            val number = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ROOT).parse(string)
            return (number.toDouble() * metric.multiplier).toLong()
        }
    }
    throw UnsupportedOperationException()
}
```

Результат:

```
parse("12M")   # 12000000
parse("26.8M") # 26800000
parse("47K")   # 47000
parse("27.8K") # 27800
parse("1,171") # 1171
parse("232")   # 232
```

Answer (score 1):

Для парсинга числа можно воспользоваться классом `DecimalFormat`, для сопоставления буквенного суффикса - мапой значений.  Число и суффикс можно определить при помощи регулярного выражения `(?i)(\d[\d.,]*)([kmg]?)`:

- `(?i)` - сравнение без учета регистра
- `(\d[\d.,]*)` - группа 1 - число
- `([kmg]?)` - группа 2 - опциональный суффикс

```java
Map<String, Long> suffixes = Map.of(
    "K", 1_000L,
    "M", 1_000_000L,
    "G", 1_000_000_000L
);

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.#", new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US));
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)(\\d[\\d.,]*)([kmg]?)");

for (String s : new String[]{"0.01M", "1k", "2,345", "3.456g", "7,890,123.456K", "7654k"}) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.find()) {
        long v = (long)(df.parse(m.group(1)).doubleValue() * suffixes.getOrDefault(m.group(2).toUpperCase(), 1L));
        System.out.println(s + " -> " + v); 
    } else {
        System.out.println("Non-matched: " + s);
    }
}
```

```
0.01M -> 10000
1k -> 1000
2,345 -> 2345
3.456g -> 3456000000
7,890,123.456K -> 7890123456
7654k -> 7654000
```